# Simple HTML page has Error 500 on mobile devices but not on desktop

Tags: mobile, web, header, html

Ok, so I have a VERY SIMPLE html page on a website so people can access a couple files.

The problem is that this page loads fine from a desktop computer using a standard browser, but when attempting to view it on a mobile device, I get ERROR 500.  So, is there some simple header info I need to add to the file to get it to display on a mobile device?

Here's the URL:

http://www.customsoftwarezone.com/GH/index.html

Here's the entire HTML:

```
<br/>
Vocal Solos - Gregory Harrison:
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="http://www.customsoftwarezone.com/GH/01.mp3">Bring Him Home</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="http://www.customsoftwarezone.com/GH/02.mp3">On The Street Where You Live</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="http://www.customsoftwarezone.com/GH/03.mp3">I Won't Give Up</a>
<br/>
```

Comment: 500 error is from the server. Can you paste the url of your code?

Comment: Browser is a browser be it on Desktop or on a Mobile. It shouldn't require any additional headers. The issue is with something else.

Comment: Can you post the urls you are using on Desktop and on Mobile?

Comment: I see a `is_mobile` cookie is being set. What are you doing with that?

Comment: I am doing nothing with any cookies.  The entirety of the website is in the text above.  This is just html, no javascript, no cookies.  Just simple text only pretty much...

Comment: Where is it being hosted?

Comment: ipage.com is where it is being hosted.

Comment: Do you see a `.htaccess` file in your root directory or in the `/gh/` directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect mobile browser by using jquery, such that:

```
if(jQuery.browser.mobile)
{
   console.log('You are using a mobile device!');
}
else
{
   console.log('You are not using a mobile device!');
}
```